# Can't fix this problem: Syntax Error: Can't Assign to Operator

Tags: python, syntax

Sorry if this seems repetitive but I can't find anywhere that solves my problem. When in python trying to multiply a constant and a variable it is coming up with the syntax error.  I can't find a way to fix it.
The first part is some tkinter stuff.

```
def DIESEL():
    Diesel = Tk()
    diesel = Label(Diesel, width=20, text="Diesel", font=30).grid(row=0, column=0)
    DIesel = Label(Diesel, width=50, text="Enter how much Diesel you have bought in litres.", font=20).grid(row=1, column=0)
    a = Entry(Diesel, width=50, bg="grey", fg="white", borderwidth=4)
    a.grid(row=2, column=0)
    Seperator6 = Label(Diesel, text=" ", width=46, height=2).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2) 
    c=2
    a.get = b
    c * b = d
    print(d)
    myFile=open("CarbnCal.txt", " w ") 
    myFile.write(b)
    myFile.close
    Diesel.mainloop()
```

The problem is on the line `c * b = d` in front of the c is a red highlighted area and an error saying:

```
Syntax Error can't assign to opperator
```

Comment: You can't have `c * b` on the lhs of an assignment statement, this is probably meant to be `d = c*b` but the line above `a.get = b` is also questionable, perhaps, `b = a.get()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not correct.
If you want to assign a value to `d`, use:

```py
d = c * b
```

Comment: Likewise `b = a.get()`; that one is trickier, because you can actually create a new instance attribute `get` that shadows the method `Label.get`.